# How can I use querySelector within activeElement?

Tags: javascript

How can I use `querySelector` in an `activeElement`?

*e.g.* this gives me an error of `null`:

```
document.activeElement.querySelector('.something').classList.add('something else');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. It will look for matches *within* the element. In your code, unless there's an element with the class `something` *within* the element that's active as of when that code runs, you'll get an error because `querySelector` returns `null` if it doesn't find an element, but you're trying to access the `classList` property of that `null`.

Here's an example of it working (because the element I'm looking for **is** within `activeElement`):

```js
document.getElementById("container").focus();
document.activeElement.querySelector(".something").classList.add('else');
```

```css
.else {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="something">this is the .something element; the class <code>else</code> makes it green</div>
</div>
```

You probably want a guard:

```
var something = document.activeElement.querySelector('.something');
if (something) {
    something.classList.add('else');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think the original DOM I was trying to check was actually a little different to what I thought it was, and the element I was searching for was not inside another element. Your answer and demo has helped me realise that, and I can see it working now.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to check whether the active element *has itself* a certain class (or fulfills some other CSS condition). Then `querySelector` is not what you need.

Instead you could use the [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) method and make the `classList.add` conditional with an `if`:

```
if (document.activeElement.matches('.something')) { 
    document.activeElement.classList.add('something else');
}
```

Be aware that `document.activeElement` may be `null` when there is currently no active element. So you need to protect your code for that situation.

Comment: It [would appear not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52263117/how-can-i-use-queryselector-within-activeelement/52263145?noredirect=1#comment91474243_52263145).

Comment: Sorry, thank you anyway, your answer is still useful to me! Which is why I marked it up

Answer (score -1):

Using vanilla JavaScript :

```js
function addClassToElementInActiveElement ( selector, className )
{
  // Get the active element, returns the element focused, body or null
  let activeElement = document.activeElement;
  
  if ( activeElement !== null )
  {
    // Get thet target from the selector provided, returns a DOM element or null
    let target = activeElement.querySelector( selector );
    
    if ( target !== null )
    {
      target.classList.add( className );
    }
    else
    {
      // Handle selector not found here
    }
  }
  else
  {
    // Handle no active element here
  }
}

// Usage example
addClassToElementInActiveElement ( '.get-me', 'got-you' );
```

```css
body
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.container
{
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #00F;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.got-you
{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" autofocus>
  <div class="get-me">Get me !</div>
  <div>Dont get me !</div>
  <div>Dont get me !</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="get-me">Dont get me !</div>
  <div>Dont get me !</div>
  <div>Dont get me !</div>
</div>
```